# Download file works in second click

Tags: java, primefaces

```
    <h:form  id="ybForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <p:dataTable id="fileList" value="#{yeniBelgeBean.listResim}" var="fileList" emptyMessage="Herhangi bir kayıt bulunmamaktadır.">
          <p:column headerText="Ek"> 
             <p:commandButton value="indir"  ajax="false" immediate="true">
               <p:fileDownload value="#{yeniBelgeBean.yazdir(fileList.id)}" />
            </p:commandButton>
          </p:column>
          <p:column bla bla..
             .....
         </p:column>
       </p:dataTable>
   </h:from>
```

When I click the button my page is update itself but no download, second click the file download. My bean is in conversation scope.

Any idea?

Comment: Try removing immediate="true"

Comment: show yeniBelgeBean yazdir method